# Php/Laravel - get the last element from request array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the last element of the request array in foreach loop that would look something like this:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "files/uploads/articles/bear_PNG1183.png"
  1 => "files/uploads/articles/bear_PNG1189.png"
  2 => "files/uploads/articles/bear_PNG1188.png"
  3 => "files/uploads/articles/bear_PNG1182 (1).png"
  4 => "files/uploads/articles/bear_PNG1190.png"
]
```

But I can't use the `end()` function because then I get:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

This is how foreach function looks like:

```
foreach ($request->get('uploadedItems') as $file) {

          //make a new directory for the article and move all the uploaded files to it
          $filePathArr = explode('/', $file);
          $lastItem = array_pop($filePathArr);
          array_push($filePathArr, $article->id, $lastItem);
          $newPath = implode('/', $filePathArr);
          $articleDirectory = $this->destinationPath.'/'.$article->id;

          if(!File::exists($articleDirectory))
            File::makeDirectory($articleDirectory, 0755, true);

          File::move(public_path($file), public_path($newPath));

          if(end($request->get('uploadedItems')) == $file){
              dd($file);
          }

          Media::create(['path' => $newPath, 'article_id' => $article->id]);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why call `$request->get('uploadedItems')` multiple times?  Call it once and assign it to a variable before the loop or:

```
foreach ($files = $request->get('uploadedItems') as $file) {

    if(end($files) == $file){
        dd($file);
    }

}
```